# Turn off autocomplete in FireFox

Tags: forms, firefox, autocomplete, passwords

I have a login that remembers the users username and password. How do you disable the autofill function for the password? Using `autocomplete="off"` works fine in `IE` but not in `Firefox`.

```
<td><input  type="password" name="pass" redisplay="false" autocomplete="off" /></td>
```

I know `FireFox` has begun ignoring this attribute after FF 30. Is there a work around to disable it in the `HTML` form?

Comment: Users find it irritating when autocomplete fails so if you find a workaround and it becomes popular I imagine that the Firefox developers that work on browser UI issues will change it so that your workaround no longer works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put a hidden empty text field between username and password

```
<input type="text" name="username">
<!-- disables autocomplete --><input type="text" style="display:none">
<input type="password" name="password">
```